# How to calculate the coordinates of the 4 corners (edge) of the map with BingMap?

Tags: c#, geolocation, coordinates, bing-maps

I work with bing from some days. I can display an image with my bing map coordinates lontitude and latitude.

But **I would like to calculate the coordinates** of location in **the 4 edges of my image**.
For now the only thing I know is the central point of origin.
The problem is that I'm limited to API. I work for a games xna c # and unfortunately **can not use the Class Map** from microsoft :-(. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846504.aspx

**I know the following values:** (sample value)

LevelZoom: 17

ImageWidth: 800 px

Imageheight: 800 px

Lat: 46.6023

Longitude: 7.0964

Is it possible to calculate the coordinates of the 4 corners of my image with these 5 values ​​known? Here is a drawing explaining what I want.
[image]
Thanks a lot

Comment: How exact do you need to be...  Some basic trig might get you close, but if you have to factor in curvature of the earth, it can get very messy

Comment: Yes ok. But my zoom is rather high. My rectangle covers about 4km an average of 4km. This is a small map. So curvature does not have much effect. I am looking for just a algorithmic / mathematical formula to calculate this "approximate"

Comment: Which is why I asked.... but the one problem is when you get to higher latitudes, the "size" of 1 degree longitude can get quite small, so you do need to factor that in to any algorithm if you are going to be dealing with maps in the extreme north and south latitudes

Comment: Ah okay. I understand. Thank you very much for this tip. It is precisely to calculate the elevation of the entire map. This is his I need four corners coordinated. To determine an area rectange my card

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the scale 1.19 m/pixel given by the bing maps api for a level 17 zoom this gives us 800 * 1.19 = 95'000 meters edges 
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa940990.aspx)

You should be able to calculate it this way : (alorithm : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/algorithm-for-offsetting-a-latitude-longitude-by-some-amount-of-meters)

```
 //Position, decimal degrees
 lat = 46.6023
 lon = 7.0964

 //Earth’s radius, sphere
 R=6378137

 // DO THE SAME FOR B C D

 //offsets in meters for A
 dn = -47600
 de = -47600

 //Coordinate offsets in radians
 dLat = dn/R                      // -0.0074629942881440144669203562106
 dLon = de/(R*Cos(Pi*lat/180))    // -0.00746374633301685016002447644032

 //OffsetPosition, decimal degrees
 latA = lat + dLat * 180/Pi // 46.174701924759107796879309401922
 lonA = lon + dLon * 180/Pi // 6.6687588357618898589751458712973
```

This use a simplified flat earth calculation which is not the most accurate method but should meet your need though.

Comment: Waouhhhhhh !! Thank's a lot ! thank you for taking the time to me! This is what I call "a real good answer" ^ ^